# Circular header dependency

Tags: c, visual-studio, circular-dependency

I am stuck on (what i think is) a circular dependency problem in VS2017 coding in c.

I tried looking up the problem, and found a lot of similar problems on stackoverflow, but I can't seem to get my problem solved with those questions.

My code:

*main.c*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "travelers.h"
#include "trip.h"

int main(void) {

    int nTravelers = 0;
    int nTrips = 0;

    Traveler *travelersArray = (Traveler*)calloc(nTravelers, sizeof(Traveler));
    Trip *tripsArray = (Trip*)calloc(nTrips, sizeof(Trip));

    return 0;
}
```

*travelers.h*

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned int id;
    char *name;
    char *adress;
    char *residence;
} Traveler;
```

*trip.h*

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned int id;
    char *touringCar;
    char *destination;
    char *date;
    Traveler *travelers;
    unsigned int amount;
} Trip;
```

the `travelers.c` and `trip.c` files are only contain `#include "travelers.h"`/`#include "trip.h"`

The error occurs only in `trip.h` at `Traveler *travelers;`:

[image: Error(s)]

I don't know how to resolve this.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10122621/c-circular-dependency) looks like the same problem, but I couldnt translate it to my code.

Any help is apriciated.

Comment: Impossible to say from the information we have. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: On a side note, [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of malloc() and family in C..](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917)

Comment: There is no circular anything here. Use appropriate header guards *and `#include` directives* in each header file.

Comment: The code you show here does not compile, but not for the reason you write but only because `nTravelers` and `nTrips` are not declared.

Comment: Side note: you also forgot `#include <stdlib.h>`

Comment: @MichaelWalz .... which s/he would have noticed if s/he hadan't casted `calloc()` as not necessary in C.

Comment: Also please refrain from posting images of text.

Comment: @alk correct, but not including `stdlib.h` is really an error nowadays. I get a warning `'calloc' undefined; assuming extern returning int`.

Comment: @MichaelWalz: Agreed. Still not everybody considers a warning (as you got) an "error".

Comment: I rolled back your question to its (more or less) original state. As else comments/answers would not be understandable any more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No cycles here.

If `trip.c` includes `trip.h` is shall also include `travelers.h` as its definitions (`Trip`) depends on the latter (`Traveller`).

---

Knowing this, one could include `travelers.h` into `trip.h`. Still, this complicates things, so it is a good idea to 1st of all add to every header so call header-guards, protecting against duplicate definitions on pre-processor level.

Doing so made the headers look like this:

*travelers.h*

```
#ifndef TRAVELERS_H
#define TRAVELERS_H

typedef struct {
    unsigned int id;
    char *name;
    char *adress;
    char *residence;
} Traveler;


#endif  // #ifndef TRAVELERS_H
```

*trip.h*

```
#ifndef TRIP_H
#define TRIP_H

#include "travelers.h"  // makes including it unnecessary where trip.h is included

typedef struct {
    unsigned int id;
    char *touringCar;
    char *destination;
    char *date;
    Traveler *travelers;
    unsigned int amount;
} Trip;


#endif // #ifndef TRIP_H
```

Comment: ...and in the order of first `travelers.h` and then `trip.h`so that `Traveler` is known before it is used in `Trip`.

Comment: I implemented this in my code, including the changes for the calloc() casting, but it still gives me the same error. I edited the code in the question.

Comment: @NoëlVissers: Did you do a **re**build?

Comment: @alk Im sorry. Totally forgot that. I usually dont program in c or in VS. But now it works. Thank you verry much sir!

Answer (score 0):

As a remark, the error is caused by the `typedef`. C accepts *opaque* structs provided you do not need their implementation details:

a.h:

```
struct A {
        int aVal;
        const char * astr;
};
```

a.c:

```
#include "a.h"

const char *getAStr(struct A*a) {
        return a->astr;
}
```

b.h

```
const char *getName(struct B*);

struct B {
        int bVal;
        struct A *a;
};
```

b.c

```
#include "b.h"

const char *getAStr(struct A*);

const char * getName(struct B* b) {
        return getAStr(b->a);
}
```

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "a.h"
#include "b.h"

int main() {
        struct A a = { 1, "foo" };
        struct B b = { 2, &a };

        printf("%d - %d : %s\n", b.bVal, b.a->aVal, getName(&b));
        return 0;
}
```

compiles and links without even a warning while in b.c nothing is known on `struct A` **except** that it is a struct.