# Should aliased name or origin name be used as forward declaration?

Tags: c++, alias, forward-declaration

If a name is aliased by `using` keyword, and this name need be used as a forward declaration, which name should be used? The origin name or the new name? The name could refer to a plain data type, a class, or a namespace.

For example:

A.h:

```
using ID = int;
namespace AA {class C;}
using namespace BB = AA;
```

B.cpp

```
//here function f is implemented
#include "A.h"
```

B.h: here ID need a forward declaration

```
class ID;
namespace BB {class C;}
void f(ID i, BB::C c);
```

or we could only choose belowing one

```
//class int;
namespace AA {int C;}
void f(int i, AA::C c);
```

Comment: How is `class int` valid syntax?

Comment: If, for some reason, you can't include `A.h` inside of `B.h`, then you have to recreate the alias with a new `using ID = int;`. Aliases can't be forward declared.

Comment: Is it that you really cannot include `A.h` in `B.h`, as @Someprogrammerdude suspected already? If *not*, then your problems are gone by just doing so...

Comment: (related: [C circular dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10122621/c-circular-dependency))

Comment: @user202729 Just fixed it.

Comment: It is not a good idea to give `BB` different meanings in different headers or not  (might be an ODR violation even)