# C circular dependency for embedded types (not pointer)

Tags: c

I came across this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10122621/c-circular-dependency) for the problem and it solved by forward referencing the struct.

But I've a different scenario, in my case the struct is embedded. My actual problem has a long dependency chain, `a -> b -> c -> d -> a` (`->` means includes or depends upon) so I'm going to use the given solution from the post.

Q. Is it possible to have embedded type `struct edgelist edges`?

**Error**: 1field has incomplete type 'struct edgeList'

```
struct edgelist;

typedef struct
{
    char* name;
    float x, y;
    struct edgelist* edges;
} vertex;
```

Comment: Are you asking because it isn't working?

Comment: _"Q. Is it possible to have embedded type struct edgelist edges?"_. I guess yes it's possible, but you need to elaborate, the question is unclear. Embedded in what?

Comment: yes it's not working, as soon as I change it to embedded type, it throws a series of errors something on the line like `1field has incomplete type 'struct EdgeList` for example.

Comment: ok, let me update it. so you are saying with forward declaration its possible for embedded types.

Comment: The code you show here is fine. Please show a [mcve]

Comment: If `struct edgelist` is defined somewhere else, say in another c file, then you can't use it as a member of another struct, because it is an incomplete type. The compiler can work with pointers to incomplete types, because it only needs to know that the type exists somewhere, but the size of the type is irrelevant. However, to actually create a `struct edgelist` variable, or embed it into another struct, the compiler needs to know the size. So no, forward declarations can't be used this way.

Comment: Also, since you're asking about circular dependencies: a struct can of course never actually include itself (directly or indirectly), because then it would have infinite size.

Comment: @FelixG thanks for clearing this up with reasoning, so I conclude I can't use embedded types in such cyclic references.

Comment: How many iterations of your "include" chain would you expect to get if that would work? The last `a` would have to include the same elements `b->c->d->a->b->c->d->a->b->c->d->a->b->c->d->a->b->c->d->a->b->c->d->a->b->c->d->a->...` How should the compiler know when to stop?

Comment: I think it detects the second time of cyclic reference and stops there, but can be different for C++ because I have heard Rob pike complaining of C++ for repeated includes.

Answer (score 1):

This is an incomplete type:

```
struct edgelist;
```

This code is correct because it's allowed to have a *pointer* to an incomplete type:

```
typedef struct
{
    char* name;
    float x, y;
    struct edgelist* edges;   // you can have pointers to incomplete types
} vertex;
```

But as soon as you use this, your code becomes incorrect because `edges` is not a *pointer*:

```
struct edgelist edges;
```

In order to be able to use a variable of type `struct edgelist`, the struct needs to be defined somewhere.

So this would be correct:

```
struct edgelist    // declares an actual (complete) type struct edgelist
{
  // whatever declaration you want
};

struct edgelist edges;
```